# Is it possible to publish/subscribe to a remote api instead of a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: meteor

I would like to retrieve Data from a remote api (via HTTP.get) and pass it to the client. Currently I manually poll the data and implemented some template helpers, that pass the data to the views.

In case of a jquery datatable I use the jquery-datatables package and that needs a published collection.

Has anyone a hint for me how to implement this?

Comment: If you're retrieving data from the API successfully on the server, can't you just upsert this into a collection server-side and then subscribe to that collection on the client, rather than passing the data to the client some other way?

Comment: I thought about that approach, but if it's possible I don't want to have redundant data. If there is no alternative, I will probably go that way, but it kinda feels "dirty" to me. :)

Comment: This is really how Meteor is designed to be used, at least if you want reactivity.  On redundant data, it should be easy to limit the data you publish from the server to the relevant API call if that's what you want, and then delete any old data from the database on a batch process when no clients are subscribed to it any more.

Comment: Of course if you don't actually want reactivity, then it's probably worth looking at an alternative datatables implementation, as I agree that this could be over-complicating matters.  There are several other packages on Atmosphere - for example [this one](https://atmospherejs.com/package/datatables-without-css).

Comment: Actually, having thought about this a bit more, this is crying out for a custom publish function.  Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onCkNRE2q0c), which shows exactly how to use the normal pub/sub model without a MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link to the video. I now have a concept of how I could implement this and benefit also from reactivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for others who might want to know how to solve this:

You'll find an example here: https://github.com/avital/publish-time/blob/master/publish-time.js

The code is shown in this 20 min video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onCkNRE2q0c

With that you'll be able to quickly implement custom publish/subscribe without using MongoDB.

@richsilv: Thanks again for pointing me to the right stuff.